# I'm getting this error in laravel SplFileInfo::getSize() when I try to save the data in database

Tags: php, laravel

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request , [

            'title'=> 'required|max:200',
            'featured' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
            'content' => 'required',
            'category_id' => 'required',
        ]);
        // dd(ini_get('upload_max_filesize'));

        $featured = $request->featured;

        $featured_new_name = time().$featured->getClientOriginalName();

        $featured->move('uploads/posts' , $featured_new_name);

        $post = Post::create([
            'title' => $request->title,
            'content' => $request->content,
            'category_id' => $request->category_id,
            'featured' => 'uploads/posts'. $featured_new_name
        ]);

        return redirect()->back();


    }
```

My max_upload_size = 2g and max_file_uploads = 20. I still get this error.
It was working fine before I got to sleep But when I checked again This error appeared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My `php.ini` was fine everything was ok with `php.ini`.
I had a Column in my database `slug`. It was not `null` by default and I was not inserting a `slug` into it. When I changed it to `Null` and submitted it again it started working.

If your `php.ini` file is fine then check your Database table in which you are uploading the file path. If you have a column in which you are not saving a value and it is not `Null` by default then change it to `Null`.

Answer (score 0):

You probably forgot to set the `post_max_size` in your php.ini to `2g` also.
Don't forget to restart your apache/web server after making php.ini changes.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I changed it to 2G but it is still not working. These are my setting in php.ini file.
`post_max_size = 2G`
`upload_max_filesize = 2G`
`max_file_uploads = 20`
The file I'm trying to upload is 68 kb image.

Comment: Found the problem I was facing.
There was a column in my table `slug` it wasn't by default null. When I changed it to null it started working.